# Bundle install repeated errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

Things were buggy on my system, so I uninstalled my old ruby directory and am now trying to reinstall things. I downloaded and installed the newest ruby version.

When I tried to run Rails server, though, it said that I needed to install a number of gems. So I ran bundle install, and it turned out that had also been uninstalled.

So I did gem install bundler, but now, whenever I run bundle install, it doesn't work. I keep getting some version of this error:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed ...
An error occurred while installing ThisGem ('0.3.4'), and Bundler cannot continue. 
Make sure that "gem install ThisGem '0.3.4' " succeeds before bundling.
```

The "gem install" command works, every time, but when I install a single gem, it just moves onto erroring at the next, which has to be installed by hand, which kind of ruins the point of Bundler.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: did you installed RubyGems. how did you installed rails in your system.

Comment: Are you using RVM or RBenv?

Answer (score 0):

Include the gem "ThisGem '0.3.4'" in your Gemfile manually and try to run:

bundle install --local